# fastest way to find special value in sql server

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

i use Sql Server and i have a query (i call it @result) that return 
all input(IN) and output(OUT) data for a special product for every days
for example:

```
+---------+----------+---------+---------+
|RowID    |   Date   |   IN(+) | OUT(-)  |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+
|100      |2001-01-01|50       |0        |
|101      |2001-01-02|20       |0        |
|102      |2001-01-03|0        |10       |
|103      |2001-01-04|0        |60       |
|104      |2001-01-05|15       |0        |
|105      |2001-01-06|35       |0        |
|106      |2001-01-07|0        |7        |
|107      |2001-01-08|0        |25       |
|108      |2001-01-09|0        |18       |
|109      |2001-01-10|50       |0        |
```

i use this query to calculate remain value for every date in my query:

```
    With cte1 as (
        Select rowID,date,
        (
        SELECT SUM(in-out) 
        FROM @result T2 WHERE T2.rowid<=T1.rowid
        ) AS remain
        From @result T1
        )
    Select * from cte1

+---------+----------+---------+---------+----------+
|RowID    |   Date   | IN(+)   | OUT(-)  +  remain  +
+---------+----------+---------+---------+----------+
|100      |2001-01-01|50       |0        |50        |
|101      |2001-01-02|20       |0        |70        |
|102      |2001-01-03|0        |10       |60        |
|103      |2001-01-04|0        |60       |0         |
|104      |2001-01-05|15       |0        |15        |
|105      |2001-01-06|35       |0        |50        |
|106      |2001-01-07|0        |7        |43        |
|107      |2001-01-08|0        |25       |18        |
|108      |2001-01-09|0        |18       |0         |
|109      |2001-01-10|50       |0        |50        |
```

i want to find 3 last record that remain field is equal zero and save this field (date and id) on local variable.
note:i have very much record (about milion) for every product and it is very slow to find all value for all product.

i use this query:

```
    With cte1 as (
        Select rowID,date,
        (
        SELECT SUM(in-out) 
        FROM @result T2 WHERE T2.rowid<=T1.rowid
        ) AS remain
        From @result T1
        )
    Select cte1.RowID, cte1.Date 
    From cte1 Where mandeh = 0
    order by cte1.rowID Desc
```

but this is very slow.

Question :

is my query the best way for find zero value and what i can do to speed up my query.

thanks.

=========================================================================
this is structure of Data table

```
Create table    TestSpeed 
        (
            rowID         int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
            G_date  SmallDateTime,
            G_Num  integer,
            in_data Numeric(18,2),
            Out_data    Numeric(18,2)
        )
```

i export data of this table and you can download and import data to table for test query speed.
[Data For Import](http://s1.freeupload.ir/files/8/6czx9igar2w0l4/TestSpeed.rar)

my last query that return special value is :

```
        With cte1 as (
                Select rowID ,G_date,G_Num,in_data,Out_data ,
                (
                SELECT SUM(in_data-Out_data) 
                FROM Testspeed T2 WHERE T2.rowid<=T1.rowid
                ) AS Remain
                From Testspeed T1
            ), 
     cte2 As 
    (
    Select Top 3 * From cte1 
    Where Remain = 0
    Order By rowid Desc
    )
    Select * From cte2
```

this query run at 4 minute on my pc.

thanks very much

Comment: do you have any index on `@result`?

Comment: Where does "mandeh" com from?

Comment: btw: Do NOT use reserved words as column names!

Comment: show us the table definiton of `@result`.

Answer (score 0):

Some questions? How many rows will there be in @results?
Why is there a table variable? With many rows you will miss the advantage of indexes...

If I understand this correctly, you are building a "running sum". With SQL Server 2012+ you could use SUM() OVER to achieve this more easily...

Assuming that your "mandeh" is the "remain" and it is just a translation error you could try this, which should procude the same result:

```
SELECT rowID
      ,[date]
      ,remain.SumInOut AS remain
From @result T1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT SUM([in]-[out]) AS SumInOut 
    FROM @result T2 
    WHERE T2.rowid<=T1.rowid
) AS remain
WHERE remain.SumInOut = 0
ORDER BY rowID DESC
```

Comment: Generally better to ask those questions via comments under the original question, and **then** writing your answer

Comment: i cant use sql server 2012 (and new feature for example CROSS APPLY) because i have many customer that use my application with sql server 2008.

Comment: in fact i have 2 table that one of them is all entry record  for all product and another all exit record for all product. at first i create @resut table to filter all record for one product (from join Entry And Exit Table).

Comment: @Ali, If both carry the same rowID you must join them... Don't know your structure... Just took your query and tried to understand what you want to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

i didn't load your data but a sample with about 1.5mio rows. the query took ~5sec including loading the sample.

```
with cte as (
  select rowID    = max(rowID) + 1
       , G_date   = cast ( getdate()     as SmallDateTime)
       , In_calc  = cast ( SUM(in_data)  as numeric(18,2)) 
       , Out_calc = cast ( SUM(out_data) as numeric(18,2)) 
       , In_data  = cast ( 0             as numeric(18,2))
       , Out_data = cast ( 0             as numeric(18,2)) 
       , Remain   = cast ( SUM(in_data) - SUM(out_data) as numeric(18,2)) 
       , Remain0  = 0
  from @result
  union all 
  select rowID    = r.rowID
       , G_date   = r.G_date
       , In_calc  = cast ( cte.in_data  - r.in_data   as numeric(18,2))  
       , Out_calc = cast ( cte.out_data - r.out_data  as numeric(18,2)) 
       , In_data  = cast ( cte.in_data                as numeric(18,2)) 
       , Out_data = cast ( cte.out_data               as numeric(18,2)) 
       , Remain   = cast ( cte.in_data - cte.out_data as numeric(18,2)) 
       , Remain0  = case when cte.in_data <= cte.out_data then cte.Remain0 + 1 else cte.Remain0 end
  from @result r join cte on r.rowID=cte.rowID-1
  where cte.Remain0 < 3
)
select * from cte where Remain0 between 1 and 3
option (maxrecursion=0)  -- <-- if you need more than 100 recursion until you have 3 times zero
```

you start with the current status and go back row by row, `In_data` and `Out_data` is the amount you have and base to calculate the `Remain`.
`Remain0`counts how often you hit bottom.

Comment: your query have error: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Then'. when i use "case when cte.in_data - cte.out_data = 0 then" this error return to me Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "In_calc" of recursive query "cte".
Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "Out_calc" of recursive query "cte".

Comment: error on query : Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "In_calc" of recursive query "cte".
Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "Out_calc" of recursive query "cte".
Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "Remain" of recursive query "cte".

Comment: @Ali yeah, i see, i tried it on another box without inet, made a few typos during copy and i tried it with `int` instead of `numeric`

Comment: thanks but your query return not correct data. can you test it with my data?

Comment: this query return 4 last record of data(only negative out_data value)